# Understanding floating point multiplication under different representations

Tags: python, precision

I was multiplying a floating point number by hundred, only to see it round it off. The same does not happen when multiplying by 10 or 1000.

`546.55 * 100 = 54654.99999999999`

`546.55 * 10 * 10 = 54655.0`

`546.55 * 1000 = 546550.0` (this is something I tried just to see how it behaves on powers of 10 greater than 100)

Shouldn't multiplication by 100 and multiplication by 10*10 have the same result? Will an interpreter understand `100` and `10*10` as different?

Comment: It might be helpful for you to also take note that `10 * 10 * 546.55 !=  546.55 * 10 * 10`

Comment: @rrauenza thanks for taking a look. is it because of the order of resolution?